# How to increase the height of a cell in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make a GUI for my ai and am attempting to make a template for it. But my 'TESTER-MAN' button does not fill the white space below it, leaving a. gap and what would be shrinking my image that will go there. I would like to get some help on attempting to increase the height of the cell to fill the white space.

python3:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class BoxLayoutE(BoxLayout):
    pass

class guiApp(App):
    pass


guiApp().run()
```

.kv

```
 BoxLayoutE:



<BoxLayoutE>:

orientation: "vertical"
Button:
    text: "TESTER-MAN"

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "1"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, None
    Button:
        text: "2"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, None
    Button:
        text: "3"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, None
Button:
    text: "A"
    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
Button:
    text: "B"
    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
Button:
    text: "C"
    color: 0, 0, 1, 1
```

Picture of the GUI and where the [image: picture of gui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your horizontal `BoxLayout`, you have assigned `size_hint` to `(.5, None)` for each of the `Buttons`, so that those `Buttons` do not fill the `BoxLayout` vertically. Try changing that part of the `kv` to:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "1"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, 1
    Button:
        text: "2"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, 1
    Button:
        text: "3"
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: .5, 1
```

Note that the `size_hints` are now `.5, 1`, so the `Buttons` fill the space vertically.